# How to pass an object to a view from a tree on primefaces

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have developed a navigation menu with primefaces tree component. The tree nodes have a Project object as data inside. I want to be able to load a view with the project details which loads dynamically when I click each project.

For that I have defined an ajax event select on the tree:

```
<h:form>
    <p:tree value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node"
                    selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}" id="tree" >
                    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#treeBean.onNodeSelect}"/>
        <p:treeNode styleClass="treeNode">
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
</h:form>
```

Which calls a onNodeSelectMethod in the treeManagedBean:

```
@ViewScoped
@Component("treeBean")
@ManagedBean
public class TreeManagedBean{

private Project selectedProject;

public Project getSelectedProject(){
    return selectedProject;
}

public void setSelectedProject(Project project){
    this.selectedProject = project;
}

    public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {
            this.selectedProject = (Project)event.getTreeNode().getData();
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ConfigurableNavigationHandler handler = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)             context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
            handler.performNavigation("viewProject");
        }
```

And then I load viewProject.xhtml via faces-config.xml, and populate the property in the other managedBean:

```
@Component("projectView")
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class ProjectView {
    @ManagedProperty("#{treeBean.selectedProject}")
    private Project project; 
}
```

The view loads without any errors, but the property is never set. The ajax call works and is setting the property in the first bean. Is this the way to do it?

Comment: Will Observer pattern do it for you?? just think about it

Comment: @SanyamGoel your comment doesn't have anything to do with OP's question. If you don't know about JSF and libraries to enhance its power, stop commenting.

Comment: Did you check that you have the tree selection property as `#{treeBean.selectedNode}` and you're calling `#{treeBean.selectedProject}` in your managed bean? It should be the same name.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, if you see the TreeManagedBean, I set the selectedProject on the bean, it has setter and getter but I ommited it. Otherwise I should be doing the casting on the ProjectView, which I would prefer not to do.

Comment: Where do you set it? I can't see that in your JSF code nor in your actual code. Please provide more info to get better help.

Comment: I have added the getter,setter and property I set. I assign it on this line: this.selectedProject = (Project)event.getTreeNode().getData();

Comment: It could be that the `TreeManagedBean` bean is destroyed when you navigate to a new view, thus getting a null value in your `ProjectView` bean. Try to store the `selectedProject` data in a wider scope like session and retrieve it from there in your `ProjectView` constructor or `@PostConstruct` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just adding an identifier to the managedBeans, for that I was obliged to provide a default constructor:

```
@ViewScoped
@Component("treeBean")
@ManagedBean("treeBean")
public class TreeManagedBean{ 
   public TreeManagedBean(){}
}
```

and

```
@Component("projectView")
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean("projectView")
public class ProjectView {
    @ManagedProperty("#{treeBean.selectedProject}")
    private Project project; 
    public ProjectView(){}
}
```